# Why do I still get random months even though I set the BETWEEN method in my statement when I tried to run in my statement?

Tags: javascript, mysql

`I just realize I posted the wrong code about my question earlier`

Why do I still get random months even though I set the BETWEEN method in my statement when I tried to run in my nodejs? I am using mysql2

```
SELECT
    u.department,
    YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tlc.time, ',', 1), '%d/%m/%y')) AS year,
    DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tlc.time, ',', 1), '%d/%m/%y'), '%b') AS month,
    COUNT(*) AS event_count
FROM
    userlibrary tlc
LEFT JOIN
    users u ON tlc.userfullname = u.fullname
WHERE
    u.type = 'STUDENTS'
    AND YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tlc.time, ',', 1), '%d/%m/%y')) BETWEEN ? AND ?
GROUP BY
    u.department,
    year,
    month
ORDER BY
    u.department,
    year,
    month;
    `;

const [results, fields] = await connection.query(sql, [
  type,
  `${startYear}-${from}`,
  `${endYear}-${end}`,
]);
```

*http://localhost:5000/api/result/table?from=01&startYear=2023&end=02&endYear=2023&type=students

This is my code.

So what I do is use this query, and then make the query call dynamic.

- from : 01
- end : 02
- startYear: 2022
- endYear: 2023

And this is the result I get. As you can see there are lots of results that is not between the dates I given above, when I run it on the server side

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "department": "College 1",
            "year": 2023,
            "month": "Apr",
            "event_count": 25
        },
        {
            "department": "College 1",
            "year": 2023,
            "month": "Aug",
            "event_count": 7
        },
        {
            "department": "College 1",
            "year": 2023,
            "month": "Feb",
            "event_count": 3
        },
        {
            "department": "College 1",
            "year": 2023,
            "month": "Jan",
            "event_count": 19
        },
        {
            "department": "College 1",
            "year": 2023,
            "month": "Jun",
            "event_count": 1
        },
        {
            "department": "College 1",
            "year": 2023,
            "month": "Mar",
            "event_count": 32
        },
        {
            "department": "College 1",
            "year": 2023,
            "month": "May",
            "event_count": 19
        },
        {
            "department": "College 1",
            "year": 2023,
            "month": "Oct",
            "event_count": 8
        },
        {
            "department": "College 1",
            "year": 2023,
            "month": "Sep",
            "event_count": 1
        },
        {
            "department": "College 2",
            "year": 2023,
            "month": "Apr",
            "event_count": 42
        },
        {
            "department": "College 2",
            "year": 2023,
            "month": "Aug",
            "event_count": 42
        },
        {
            "department": "College 2",
            "year": 2023,
            "month": "Dec",
            "event_count": 10
        },
        {
            "department": "College 2",
            "year": 2023,
            "month": "Feb",
            "event_count": 45
        },
        {
            "department": "College 2",
            "year": 2023,
            "month": "Jan",
            "event_count": 28
        },
        {
            "department": "College 2",
            "year": 2023,
            "month": "Jul",
            "event_count": 7
        },
        {
            "department": "College 2",
            "year": 2023,
            "month": "Jun",
            "event_count": 5
        },
        {
            "department": "College 2",
            "year": 2023,
            "month": "Mar",
            "event_count": 45
        },
        {
            "department": "College 2",
            "year": 2023,
            "month": "May",
            "event_count": 51
        },
        {
            "department": "College 2",
            "year": 2023,
            "month": "Nov",
            "event_count": 16
        },
        {
            "department": "College 2",
            "year": 2023,
            "month": "Oct",
            "event_count": 108
        },
        {
            "department": "College 2",
            "year": 2023,
            "month": "Sep",
            "event_count": 20
        },
        {
            "department": "College 3",
            "year": 2023,
            "month": "Apr",
            "event_count": 50
        },
        {
            "department": "College 3",
            "year": 2023,
            "month": "Aug",
            "event_count": 8
        },
        {
            "department": "College 3",
            "year": 2023,
            "month": "Dec",
            "event_count": 6
        },
        {
            "department": "College 3",
            "year": 2023,
            "month": "Feb",
            "event_count": 62
        },
        {
            "department": "College 3",
            "year": 2023,
            "month": "Jan",
            "event_count": 50
        },
        {
            "department": "College 3",
            "year": 2023,
            "month": "Jul",
            "event_count": 10
        },
        {
            "department": "College 3",
            "year": 2023,
            "month": "Jun",
            "event_count": 4
        },
        {
            "department": "College 3",
            "year": 2023,
            "month": "Mar",
            "event_count": 110
        },
        {
            "department": "College 3",
            "year": 2023,
            "month": "May",
            "event_count": 50
        },
        {
            "department": "College 3",
            "year": 2023,
            "month": "Nov",
            "event_count": 20
        },
        {
            "department": "College 3",
            "year": 2023,
            "month": "Oct",
            "event_count": 91
        },
        {
            "department": "College 3",
            "year": 2023,
            "month": "Sep",
            "event_count": 20
        },
        {
            "department": "College 4",
            "year": 2023,
            "month": "Apr",
            "event_count": 18
        },
        {
            "department": "College 4",
            "year": 2023,
            "month": "Aug",
            "event_count": 51
        },
        {
            "department": "College 4",
            "year": 2023,
            "month": "Feb",
            "event_count": 37
        },
        {
            "department": "College 4",
            "year": 2023,
            "month": "Jan",
            "event_count": 34
        },
        {
            "department": "College 4",
            "year": 2023,
            "month": "Mar",
            "event_count": 68
        },
        {
            "department": "College 4",
            "year": 2023,
            "month": "May",
            "event_count": 22
        },
        {
            "department": "College 4",
            "year": 2023,
            "month": "Nov",
         }
   ]
```

As you can see there are months that are not `Jan` and `Feb` included.

Comment: You should try the different parts of your query in isolation, to find which part doesn't mean/do what you intend.

Comment: YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tlc.time, ',', 1), '%d/%m/%y')) BETWEEN '2023-01' AND '2023-02' - so where is the month part tested?

Comment: Sorry, I just copied it from mySQL @P.Salmon

Comment: So how did the code end up with  '2023-01' AND '2023-02'  ?

Comment: I tried directly inputting the query in the `URL` I `provided`

Comment: Did you check how the query is **really** run? Where do yoh check for months in the given query? A year value of `2023-01` looks pretty strange to me. Shouldn't you check for something like  `tlc.time between '2023-01-01 00:00:00' and '2023-02-01 00:00:00'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, the issue you're encountering stems from the way you're filtering dates in your SQL query. The BETWEEN clause in your query is applied only to the YEAR part of your dates, not the months within those years. This means that while you are successfully filtering the results by year, you are not correctly limiting the results by month. In order to ilter both by year and by month, you need to adjust your query to explicitly include month filtering. Since your date values seem to be stored as strings in a specific format (%d/%m/%y), you'll need to parse these strings into dates that MySQL can understand and then filter based on both year and month.

```sql
SELECT
    u.department,
    YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tlc.time, ',', 1), '%d/%m/%y')) AS year,
    DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tlc.time, ',', 1), '%d/%m/%y'), '%b') AS month,
    COUNT(*) AS event_count
FROM
    userlibrary tlc
LEFT JOIN
    users u ON tlc.userfullname = u.fullname
WHERE
    u.type = 'STUDENTS'
    AND STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tlc.time, ',', 1), '%d/%m/%y') 
    BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(?,'/',?, '/', ?), '%d/%m/%Y') 
    AND STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(?,'/',?, '/', ?), '%d/%m/%Y')
GROUP BY
    u.department,
    year,
    month
ORDER BY
    u.department,
    year,
    month;
```